# Going from erd relation to table

Tags: sql, ddl

I need to convert an erd to a set of DDL statements, which then represent the erd. I am stuck on how I translate relations to DDL statements. Say we have entity department, with primary key name, and entity employee, with primary key employeeID. The relation between them is that the employee is employed by one department. What would a correct DDL statement be to represent this.
I thought:

```
CREATE TABLE Employed (
   depName VARCHAR(255),
   employeeID VARCHAR(255),
   PRIMARY KEY(employeeID)
   FOREIGN KEY (depName)
      REFERENCES ON Department(depName)
   FOREIGN KEY (employeeID)
      REFERENCES ON Employees(employeeID)
```

, but I am not sure if it is correct or if it could be done in a better way.

Comment: Is your relationship 1:n or n:m? In other words, can an employee be employed by multiple departments?

Comment: An employee cannot be employed by multiple departments

Comment: In that case, your Employed table should not have `emplyeeID` as primary key. Either don't define a primary key at all or make it coumpound of both fields. The other thing I would change is to reference department id instead of name. Names can change...

Comment: You don't need the Employed table at all, since you dont't have a many-to-many relationship. Just put a foreign key in the Employee table that references departmentID (or the primary key of the Department table).